# endless dead letter queue (DLQ) processing when Middy.js SQS queue validator fails

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs, middy, dlq

I've got a lambda handler that processes incoming SQS events.
There is a middyJs handler with a validator middleware on top of that.
When MiddyJs validation fails the event gets stuck in an endless loop inside DLQ. 
When I throw an Error intentionally inside the handler it appears on DLQ just once. but with MiddyJs validation, it'll run through an endless loop. 
**Does anyone know what might cause this behavior?**

The middy configuration is as follows:

```js
middy(
  sqsEventLambdaHandler,
)
  .use(eventNormalizerMiddleware())
  .use(
    validator({
      eventSchema: transpileSchema(sqsEventLambdaEventSchema),
    }),
  )
  .use(sqsPartialBatchFailure());
```

And here is the error from cloudwatch:

```
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

`@middy/sqs-partial-batch-failure` is designed to work with a specific SQS configuration.

> The value ReportBatchItemFailures must be added to your Lambda's FunctionResponseTypes in the EventSourceMapping.

https://middy.js.org/docs/middlewares/sqs-partial-batch-failure#important

Comment: I've added partial failure and it's working under normal circumstances.
The problem is that it only doesn't work if I use middy middleware for validation.
In this case, it'll go through an endless loop.

Comment: Sounds like `@middy/validator` is throwing a validation error causing the endless 
 loop. Check the JSON Schema matches the input event.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to track! if the incoming event doesn't pass the schema validation I can track that by monitoring DLQ. 
What I did, was remove the validation middleware and call the validatore manually inside the handler. In this case, the failure won't cause a loop with an unknown error. let me know if you have a workaround to make it work with the middleware.

Comment: I pushed an update to the docs to warn others about this. And opened an issue https://github.com/middyjs/middy/issues/1095